# Определить iPhone через CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, iphone, media-queries

Как определить **iPhone X, iPhone Xs, iPhone 11 Pro и iPhone 12/12 Pro** через `CSS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определить iPhone X, iPhone Xs, iPhone 11 Pro и iPhone 12/12 Pro через `CSS` можно с помощью правила `@media`:

```
@media only screen 
    and (device-width: 375px) 
    and (device-height: 812px) 
    and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) { 
      /* Ваш CSS */
}
```

Данное разрешение дисплея, соотношения сторон и плотность пикселей, применимо лишь к этим моделям iPhone – iPhone X, iPhone Xs, iPhone 11 Pro и iPhone 12/12 Pro.

Comment: но это же на самом деле определяет размер экрана, а не модель.

Comment: @Эникейщик да ладно? А у кого ещё, кроме iPhone X, iPhone Xs и iPhone 11 Pro, есть такое разрешение дисплея с таким соотношением сторон и плотностью пикселей?

Comment: это не имеет значения. Таким образом вы определяете характеристики экрана, а не модель устройства. То, что такой экрана в настоящее время ставят только на интересующие вас модели, это всего лишь небольшой хак, а не достоверный способ.

Comment: И? Ты придрался к формулировке?

Comment: Да, я придрался к формулировке.

Comment: Следуя твоей логике, через JS мы определяем ответ USER AGENT, а не модель. Тоже хак?

Comment: Какая разница, по каким признакам мы определяем модель клиента? В CSS доступен лишь такой метод – и он прекрасно работает.

Comment: В юзер.агенте можно вообще написать, что угодно.

Comment: Ты ошибся, я не дизлайкал ответ. Жду извинений.

Comment: И о какой вообще аргументации идёт речь? Я тебе ничего не доказывал. Ты сам себе что-то придумал и борешься с ветряными мельницами.